# Fire event when div is visible to visitor with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

**The function:**
I want to change the class of a certain item when a user see a certain div (scrolls down to it).

**How I do it now:** I'm using this fine script (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/) wich works really fine to just fire an jquery event when a div gets visible to the user. However it only fires once. So if you scroll down the page the jquery gets executed fine. But if I scroll up and then down again it doesent fire. This is my jquery:

```
$('#myDiv').appear(function() {
        $("#aDiv").addClass("active");
});
```

**What I want to do:** Make the script execute everytime "myDiv" appear and not only the first.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to judge the div is visible or not, you can:

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    console.log($(".target").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight());
});
```

so, i don't think you need any plugin.

just judge it by the expression like:

```
if($(".target").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight()) {
    // something when the .target div visible
} else {
    // something when the .target div invisible
}
```

Comment: When using your script i get errors in the console who says like this:
a.style is undefined

Weird?

Comment: @Paparappa according to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9434 it's fixed in jQuery 1.7 :)

Answer (score 4):

By looking at the source code of the [jquery-appear plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/), it is possible to pass the argument `one`, to fire the event one time only (`one: true`), or every time it appears (`one: false`)

```js
$('#myDiv').appear(function() {
    $("#aDiv").addClass("active");
}, {
    one: false
});
```

Comment: This code didn't work however if i went in to the appear .js file and changed one to false my problem was solved. So your answer did more than inspiring me to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

I use a similar plugin but this uses the bind method and uses an event -> http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

Sample usage :

```
$('div').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible == true) {
    // element is now visible in the viewport
  } else {
    // element has gone out of viewport
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022652/get-current-scroll-position-and-pass-it-as-a-variable-with-a-link) would probably be useful for you.

Anyhow, you could probably do it without a plug-in and with a simple expression instead:

```js
var elem_top    = $("some_element").offset().top;
var elem_height = $("some_element").height();
var wind_height = $(window).height();
var scrollTop   = $(window).scrollTop;

if (elem_top > (wind_height + scrollTop) &&
   !(elem_top + elem_height) < wind_scrollTop) 
{
    //The element is inside the screen (e.g. it is directly visible)
}
```