# Simple jquery event on scroll to a div

Tags: jquery, html

I need a simple solution, to fire an event when user scroll the page to a certain div. 
i want to show that div which is currently collapsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    console.log($(".target").offset().top < $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).outerHeight());
});
```

[Source: Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050435/fire-event-when-div-is-visible-to-visitor-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks, i know it was very obvious question. but i didnt know how to ask this.