# Position element next to scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to position a element next to (and follow) the middle of the scrollbar. In other words, glue a element to the middle of the scrollbar. I guess you have to dynamically get the height and position of the scrollbar and update the elements properties with setInterval for example.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can show your code on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

For `<div id="thingy"></div>`, you can make thingy stick to the middle of the scrollbar without worrying about anything to do with the scrollbar properties.  Just make thingy look like:

```
#thingy {
     position:fixed;
     top:45%;
     bottom:45%;
     height:10%;
     right:0px;
}
```

That's assuming your element has a height of 10% the screen height and wants to be snug tight on the scrollbar which is on the left side of the page.

Comment: I can't get that to work. For me that just centers the element vertically. I want the element to start at the top where the scrollbar is when you haven't scrolled anything and then follow the position of the scrollbar. Look at this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4KAWs/1/

Comment: @user1216624 - ah, I see.  Question misunderstood :)  This will only work if you want the element to stay centered around the scrollbar...

Comment: @user1216624 Perhaps this post may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022652/get-current-scroll-position-and-pass-it-as-a-variable-with-a-link